# Python twisted event based jabber/xmpp/email/irc/chat client that listens and responds to messages

Tags: python, xmpp, chat, twisted, irc

I am looking to have my client "react" to a received message through some xml based communications medium. I was looking into xmpp with google talk, but I just need something that can quickly relay messages on an event based basis (i.e. without having a thread over a "check messages" function.)

I am using twisted to do the rest of my project, so if at all possible, it would be very helpful to use twisted for the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[wokkel](http://wokkel.ik.nu/) is an extension of twisted words that makes it super easy to develop clients and components.

[Here](http://metajack.im/2008/09/25/an-xmpp-echo-bot-with-twisted-and-wokkel/) is echobot as an example.